# How to add additional params to an XHR object (in Dropzone.JS)?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, dropzone.js

I am trying to upload my photos together with tags (a comma delimited string) sent in an argument `tagname`.

The `sending` option passed to the Dropzone.JS allows me to get the XHR object before sending the request.

```
Dropzone.options.uploadDropzone({
    // ...
    sending: function(file, xhr, formData){
        // but how to add my tags string to the params?
        // any methods like setting the header: 
        // xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")?
    }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in javascript

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "FileUploadHandler.ashx");
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("sFileTitle", document.getElementById('txtFileTitle').value);

    xhr.send(fd);
```

so you would append data in form data using key and values pair

```
var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("sFileTitle", document.getElementById('txtFileTitle').value);
    Dropzone.options.uploadDropzone({
        // ...
        sending: function(file, xhr, fd){
            // but how to add my tags string to the params?
            // any methods like setting the header: 
            // xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")?
        }
    })
```

Comment: Great! The key is to change the `formdata`, not the `xhr` obj!! I just added `formData.append({'tagname': 'example'})` inside `sending` and it works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: I had an error using your code: TypeError: Not enough arguments to FormData.append.. I solved it using: formData.append("tagname", "example");